# bold style not getting applied in outlook email sent using java program

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, outlook, html-email

When im trying to send email to outlook using javaprogram, the text with bold style is not applying.
However, i kept the below code.

```
    msg.setContent(buffer, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

But when I save the mail has html file, Im able to see the bold font.
May I know what needs to be done to make the font appear in bold style in outlook as well.
Note:Im actually using an email template and we are attaching the above buffer to the email template.

Thanks,
Balaji.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the HTML tag `<strong>` to indicate the text you want bold